# Mysql where condition for single SELECT [not all]

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, optimization

I want to calculate the **total gross amount** of a CLIENT in **all stores** and in a **specific store** both in one query. Not repeating the same query twice as I did below and also not using group_by.

```
                *Simply, I want to set a WHERE condition for just one of "SELECTS"*
```

My tables are: ***Clients*** and ***Orders***

```
Clients                                      Orders
id     name     passport                     id    client_id    store_id    gross_amount
1      Alex     xxx                          100      1           50           1000
2      Scott    zzz                          101      2           51           500
```

Expected result:

```
all_store       my_store
  1500            500
```

My query is

```
SELECT
    all_store.gross_amount,
    my_store.gross_amount
FROM
    (SELECT
       SUM(orders.gross_amount) gross_amount
    FROM
       clients
    JOIN orders ON clients.id = orders.client_id
    WHERE
       clients.passport = 'xxx' AND FROM_UNIXTIME(orders.date_time) >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 year) as all_store,
    (SELECT
       SUM(orders.gross_amount) gross_amount
    FROM
       clients
    JOIN orders ON clients.id = orders.client_id
    WHERE
       clients.passport = 'xxx' AND FROM_UNIXTIME(orders.date_time) >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 year AND clients.store_id = '51') as my_store
```

Comment: We can't see any `date_time` column in either table whose sample data you provided.  Please fix the sample data in your question.

Comment: I am sorry, forgot to add it. It is mentioned that orders.date_time (meaning it is from orders table), yet it does not change the main topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SUM` with `CASE WHEN` for given store to get gross amount for a specific store

```
SELECT
   SUM(orders.gross_amount) all_store,
   SUM(CASE WHEN clients.store_id = '51' THEN orders.gross_amount ELSE 0 END) my_store
FROM
   clients
JOIN orders ON clients.id = orders.client_id
WHERE
   clients.passport = 'xxx' AND FROM_UNIXTIME(orders.date_time) >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 year
```

Comment: thank you so much. Did not know about "CASE", learnt something new. Is it okay to use it on Large tables?

Comment: @Venda97 Yes, it can be used, query tuning will be another topic though.